# What all logs/Metrics should be enabled as part of the Diagnostic settings enablement for Azure Storage Accounts

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account

As part of a client requirement, I've been asked to set up central log repository for different Azure workloads including Storage accounts & databases. I see a default diagnostic setting in place but all of those are disabled. To enable these, we need to enable certain logs/metrics which will further be ingested into the workspace. Now I want to make a cost-effective & most accurate selection of the logs/metrics for storage accounts. Can someone with more profound knowledge into this domain enlighten me about it?

[image]
Similarly for Postgre SQL & Cosmos DB databases too, I have to make such decision. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the below points and references in detail.

**Selection:**

You can select the logs for the operations that you want to Get all the details you wish for.selection depends on the requirement.

1. A good practice is to go through your agents and monitoring settings
   and see exactly what you are logging. Capture logs which are
   `important` for your monitoring purpose.
2. Choose the `cheapest region` to create and store your log analytics
   workspace.
3. If you have very high volume of the log ingestion then it would be
   prudent to opt for `azure commitment tier`.
4. In case you need to export the log analytics data, rather than
   exporting all the data, you can `filter` it and send only relevant log
   data

Above things can significantly reduce your azure billing cost and help you to save money in using azure monitor effectively. [***Understand Azure Monitor and Log Analytics Pricing and Cost Optimization*** (azurelib.com)](https://azurelib.com/understand-azure-monitor-and-log-analytics-pricing-and-cost-optimization/)

---

**Storing:**

Log data can accumulate in your account over time which can increase the cost of storage.

1. If you need log data for only a `small period` of time, you can reduce
   your costs by modifying the `log data retention period` to less days.
2. Use `lifecycle policy` to move data between access tiers.
3. Data ingested into Log Analytics workspace can be retained at **no
   additional charge**(free) up to the **first 31 days**.

See
[***Design considerations***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/framework/services/monitoring/log-analytics/cost-optimization?msclkid=5437f44bbf2111ecb6737694b8bbf142#design-considerations) and  change the data retention  if
not needed more than that. See [***Monitoring Azure Blob Storage***
| Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/monitor-blob-storage?tabs=azure-portal).

4. Storage Insights is a dashboard on top of Azure Storage metrics and
   logs. You can use Storage Insights to examine the transaction volume
   and used capacity of all your accounts. That information can help
   you decide which accounts you might want to retire.

---

**Analyze:**

1. Analyze the used capacity and monitor the use of the container.
2. you can consider reducing the total cost by exporting logs to
   storage account, and then using a serverless query solution on top
   of log data.See [**blob storage monitoring/optimize cost for infrequent
   queries**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/blob-storage-monitoring-scenarios#optimize-cost-for-infrequent-queries)
3. Organize data into access tiers.Log Analytics has [**Commitment Tiers**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/cost-logs#commitment-tiers),
   which can save you as much as 30 percent compared to the
   Pay-As-You-Go price.
4. You should periodically review this information to determine if you
   can reduce your charges by moving to another tier

**References:**

1. [Plan and manage costs for Azure Blob Storage | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-plan-manage-costs#optimize-costs)
2. [Azure Monitor Logs pricing details - Azure Monitor | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/cost-logs#troubleshooting-why-usage-is-higher-than-expected)
3. [Azure Monitor Log Analytics too Expensive? Part 2 - Save Some Money
   | Thomas Stringer (trstringer.com)](https://trstringer.com/log-analytics-expensive-part-2-save/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20do%20need%20logs%20for%20longer%20than,Log%20Analytics%20workspaces%20retention%20to%20the%20free%20setting.?msclkid=3138c418bf2111ecbd00fa260d506ca6)